# Physics editor and sprite sheets - corona

Tags: coronasdk, physics-engine

I'm trying to create a collision for my sprite sheet objects using Physics Editor, however I can only edit 1 image of the 2 that I have in my sprite sheet. How can I edit them both? 
I made my sprite sheet through Photoshop.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate the sprite in PhotoShop first then go to Physics Editor and make one physics body for each sprite then you can put them together in Corona SDK.
I did like that for my game and it works.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bgames.h_balls

```
--// Wall RIGHT
local scaleFactor = 1.0;
local physicsData = (require "wall_right").physicsData(scaleFactor);
local wall_R = display.newImageRect(WALL_Group, "img/wall.png", 448, 397);
physics.addBody( wall_R, physicsData:get("wall") )
wall_R.bodyType = "static";

--// Wall LEFT
local scaleFactor = 1.0;
local physicsData = (require "wall_left").physicsData(scaleFactor);
local wall_L = display.newImageRect(WALL_Group, "img/wall.png", 448, 397);
physics.addBody( wall_L, physicsData:get("wall") )
wall_L.bodyType = "static";
```

This is the code i used for my game.

Comment: Hi Beri, thanks for the reply. How did you code the sprite sheet in corona from using the individual sprite images?

Comment: First you have to create the physics body in physics editor.create 2 physics body one for the first sprite and the other for the second one. And when you add them in corona it will look like they are one just like in my game.